# Libreoffice writer typing lag in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, libreoffice

I'm using LibreOffice writer 6.3 with ubuntu 18.04 and everything looks so good but the issue is that I'm experiencing obvious lag during typing, I also notice sometimes the typed word is messy as the word 2nd letter is exchanged with the 3rd letter or whatever, which frustrates me and killing my productivity.
I didn't use to experience this lag before as I'm working with both ubuntu and LibreOffice for a while now.

Edited:
This happens only when I write with two languages in the same line (e.g.: Arabic and English).

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: LibreOffice has a support site, where I found https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/157664/slow-typing-and-high-cpu-usage-after-a-certain-point/ . Suggest you check those solutions.